# Redirect to page in liferay Login

Tags: hook, liferay, liferay-6

I am creating a Hook to check-user on login, and depending on some parameters it will be redirected to one custom page or another.

I am doing this:

#### Portal.properties

```
#Gestion evento login
login.events.post=com.liferay.portal.events.AccionLogin
auth.forward.by.last.path=true
```

#### Action Class

```
public class AccionLogin extends Action {

    @Override
    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ActionException {
        try {
            doRun(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ActionException(e);
        }
    }
    protected void doRun(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();

        User usuarioLogin = PortalUtil.getUser(request);

        // Recupero la lista de roles
        ArrayList<Role> roles = UtilRoles.getIntExtRol();

        // Compruebo si el usuario pertenece al grupo
        if (UtilLdap.esGrupo(request, usuarioLogin.getScreenName())) {
            Constantes._log.info("El usuario es Interno en el Ldap vector. Gestiono su rol");
            UtilRoles.setRoleIfNotHave(usuarioLogin, roles, Constantes.INTERNOS);
            sesion.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, UtilUrls.generaLasthPath(request, Constantes.INTERNOS));
        } else {
            Constantes._log.info("El usuario es externo en el Ldap vector. Gestiono su rol");
            UtilRoles.setRoleIfNotHave(usuarioLogin, roles, Constantes.EXTERNOS);
            sesion.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, UtilUrls.generaLasthPath(request, Constantes.EXTERNOS));
        }
    }
}
```

This method:

```
sesion.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, UtilUrls.generaLasthPath(request, Constantes.EXTERNOS));
```

do it:

```
return new LastPath(StringPool.BLANK,Constantes.GROUPINTRANET+Constantes.SEPARADOR+Constantes.INICIOINTERNOS,
             new HashMap<String, String[]>());
```

Generates `group/intranet/pageforexterns`, and same for `interns` but when I login I have a cookies error and a redirect error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please translate it to English !

Comment: @VikasV I don't think there is anything of value to be translated to English. But if you still want the comments and logs translated then you can use: [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#es/en/El%20usuario%20es%20Interno%20en%20el%20Ldap%20vector.%20Gestiono%20su%20rol)  :-D

Comment: May you post that stacks you get ? (or a link to a pastebin) ?
In advance thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Instead creating new instance of LastPath, you just get LastPath object by LastPath lastPath=(LastPath)session.getAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH); and use lastPath.setPath(PATH) to avoid any errors.